# A is to Z as Z is to A. That is the key to OPEN the way

Tags: riddle

This riddle was given to me during a game. The four letter answer is a "code" that will unlock a door.  Since the word "open" was in caps I'm assuming that is part of the "rules" for figuring out the code.  I was going to try writing the alphabet forward and then backwards and match up the letters O P E and N to their corresponding letters in the backwards alphabet.  Any thoughts?

Comment: What's your question? Was your idea to turn OPEN into LKVM wrong?

Comment: My thought is that this is an incomplete question at best.   What is the rest of the "riddle"?  It's kind of difficult to tell if the approach you are suggesting is correct if the riddle is not there to test your idea.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a list of four-letter words that can be substituted as you suggest to make another four-letter word. That is, we swap a->z, b->y, c->x, etc, and check whether we still have a word when we're done:

```
slow <-> hold  
trio <-> girl  
holy <-> slob  
slim <-> horn  
torn <-> glim  
kiln <-> prom  
told <-> glow  
gild <-> trow  
holt <-> slog  
drib <-> wiry  
vugh <-> efts  
over <-> levi  
grog <-> tilt  
glib <-> tory  
york <-> blip  
girt <-> trig
```

If we include three letters words, there are a few more:

```
low <-> old  
ark <-> zip  
oft <-> lug  
art <-> zig  
all <-> zoo  
viz <-> era  
sly <-> hob  
irk <-> rip
```

Doesn't look like this will help, but your question is kind of vague...